# Bootstrap 4 Navbar Example Stuck in Mobile Mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, jinja2, bootstrap-4

Right now I'm going to through the Bootstrap material and trying to learn how to use their content with a jinja2 file I'm prepping up for a django project. When I tried copy and pasting their example code 
(specifically this example http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) 
[image]
into my project it seemed to be working however none of the dropdown elements are responsive and when it enters mobile it wont expand. This was with me using my local css and js files, so I thought I'll use the recommended cdn files on the Jinja website. Now it is functional, but it is stuck in mobile  mode. How should I resolve this problem?

Here's my source:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title>My title</title>
 <meta character="utf-8" />
 {%load staticfiles %}
 <!-- <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css'%}" type='text/css' media="screen" > -->
 <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js'%}"></script>  -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="body">


 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
       <li class="nav-item active">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item dropdown">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           Dropdown
         </a>
         <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
           <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
         </div>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
     <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
       <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
     </form>
   </div>
 </nav>


 <div>
 {% block content%}
 {% endblock %}
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bootstrap V4.0.0-alpha.6,

Replace

```
navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light
```

with

```
navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded
```

Ref : https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/

The [link](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) you added in your question is for bootstrap V4.0.0-beta.2 and in your code header files you added are for Bootstrap v4 alpha6

and you forgot to add `JQuery` in your code.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
 
        <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: This helped me, I had a similar issue & didn't realize how important it was to use the right version's documentation even for minor version updates. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome;) happy coding.